# Pass array through multiple text fields unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have the following problem :

I generate a number of boxes (in unity) that each one have 4 Text fields in it and i want to pass
through each box some values from an array step by step by click. Like this:

Boxes : 3 - given by user
Array : 3,4,5 - given by user

```
Boxes:
[] [] []

step 1: [5][][]
step 2: [4][5][]
step 3: [3][4][5]
step 4: [][3][4]
step 5: [][][3]
step 6: [][][]
```

How can i do that , im sure i miss something.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BoxScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text nr;
    public Text rezultat;
    public Text coeficient;
    public Text x;

    int nri = start.list.Capacity; 
    int[] a = { 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //array for test
    int t = 3;
    int z = 0;

    void Start () {
        nr.text = "TEST";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnMouseUp()
    {

        Text[] p;
        p = start.list[nri].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(); //list of boxes that each one have 4 labels
        p[0].text = a[t].ToString(); // p[0] is the label i want to write text in each box 
        p = start.list[z+1].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
        p[0].text = a[t -1].ToString();
        nri -= 1;  // 
        t -= 1;   // different tries of increment and decrements...
        z += 1;  //

    }
}
```

Comment: Should `step 5: [][][4]` be `step 5: [][][3]`?

Comment: And what are the boxes?

Comment: Yes, i edited that and the boxes are gameobjects (prefabs in a list) with 4 Text childs. I think i can't use loops because i want to be step by step. How can i approach that ?

Comment: Use the logic that you would if you were to use a loop and then just put the loop variable out as a field and have the event handler increment the value for you.

Comment: what is `start.list`?

Comment: start is the class where i can find the list of gameobjects...the code is commented...